# How to use RETURNS TABLE with an existing table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, set-returning-functions

From the PostgreSQL [documentation here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE):

> There is another way to declare a function as returning a set, which
>   is to use the syntax RETURNS TABLE(columns). ... This notation is specified in recent versions of the SQL standard, and thus may be more portable than using SETOF.

This sounds as if `RETURNS TABLE` is a newer, more portable style to return multiple rows. But I am not sure if the two syntaxes are equivalent.

I was wondering if we can actually use `RETURNS TABLE` to **replace** `RETURNS SETOF`?

In particular, one case I haven't figured out is: if we have an existing table `foo` and its associated composite type, how can we use it in `RETURNS TABLE`?

Using the example for the above link, can the following be rewritten using `RETURNS TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (fooid int, foosubid int, fooname text);
CREATE FUNCTION getfoo(int) RETURNS SETOF foo AS $$
    SELECT * FROM foo WHERE fooid = $1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

So far, I tried  to use `RETURNS TABLE (foo.*)` and `RETURNS TABLE (foo)`, which didn't work.

Comment: Confuse?  Attracted by the question's title and its key-words? See below [the answer for google-readers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/258674/90651).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PS: sorry for my comments, I was developing a complex code and I have a small error that seems a stupid PostgreSQL restriction on a "returing table" part... I was stupid, instead of concentrating and solving it, I used the internet (search engine put me here). Now, this wiki-answer is to help other readers, called by  search engine and attracted by the title of the question.

Thanks to @dezso (was a correct answer) and, please all readers, **you can edit this question** to be more didactic, it is a Wiki.

---

### Since PostgreSQL-v8 we can do it! We can RETURNS EXISTING_TABLE_NAME

In its Guide, in all PostgreSQL versions, from [since pg v8](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-TABLE-FUNCTIONS) to [current version](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-TABLE-FUNCTIONS), all have a section named  *"SQL Functions as Table Sources"*. Let's reproduce the Guide's example with some simplifications:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (fooid int, foosubid int, fooname text);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 1, 'Joe'), (1, 2, 'Ed'), (2, 1, 'Mary');

CREATE FUNCTION getfoo(int) RETURNS SETOF foo AS $$
    SELECT * FROM foo WHERE fooid = $1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT * FROM getfoo(1);
```

It is running as expected, it is perfect!

```
 fooid | foosubid | fooname
-------+----------+---------
     1 |        1 | Joe
     1 |        2 | Ed
```

The question "How to use RETURNS TABLE with an existing table in PostgreSQL?" have a good answer since pg v8... This is the way we do it in the last 15 years, **the syntax is:
  `RETURNS SETOF <EXISTING_TABLE_NAME>`**.

### Use clause TABLE as instantaneous CREATE TABLE for returning

The @tinlyx's confusion, explainded on his question, is about the use of the clause `TABLE` instead of `SETOF`... To think using the "PostgreSQL syntax logic", we must  first remember that `RETURN <EXISTING_TABLE_NAME>` is also valid, and it has the same behavior   that `RETURN <EXISTING_TYPE_NAME>`. Is natural to return only one row.

Next step, remember that we declare a tuple with the CREATE TABLE clause (<tuple_description>), therefore, a good syntax to express an "instant-define-tuple table" is RETURN TABLE (<tuple_description>), and it makes sense to return TABLE -type, which is like an array type, will return several instances (TABLE is a set of tuples).

Next step, remember that we declare a [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) with the `CREATE TABLE (<tuple_description>)` clause, therefore, a good syntax to express an "instantaneous table-definition" is `RETURN TABLE (<tuple_description>)`; and it makes sense to return Table-type, that is like Array-type, they return multiple instances (TABLE is a set of tuples).

The "modern thing" in PostgreSQL (!) is what @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister showed, the `RETURNS TABLE (LIKE <table_name>)` syntax.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getfoo2(int) RETURNS TABLE (LIKE foo) AS $$ -- working fine!
    SELECT * FROM foo WHERE fooid = $1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
SELECT * FROM getfoo2(1); -- same result as getfoo(1)
```

---

### Many ways to do the same, a summary:

Expliciting the table name (two ways) or type name:

- `RETURNS TABLE (LIKE <table_name>)` (modern and good)
- `RETURNS SETOF <table_name>` (old but good)
- `RETURNS SETOF <type_name>` (after  `CREATE TYPE <type_name> (<tuple_description>)`)

Implicit/generic ways, by anonymous types:

- `RETURNS SETOF  RECORD` (generic but somethimes a problem)
- (exist something as?) `RETURNS SETOF  ROW?`

Instantaneous table-definition:

- `RETURNS TABLE (<tuple_description>)`
- (no `RETURNS`) using `OUT` in the parameter list.

For the last case, using our example to illustrate: 
`CREATE FUNCTION getfoo(int, OUT fooid int, OUT foosubid int, OUT fooname text)`

For dynamic and/or polymophic input you must [check this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751557/287948).

### Best practice?

There are many ways to do the same, so, there are a "best one"?

As syntax I prefer the use of `RETURNS TABLE (LIKE <table_name>)`, that is explicit: no confusion with "implicit RECORD", no fear of incompatibilities...

Important for library management, `DROP TABLE foo CASCADE` will drop also the function: in any syntax (`returns table` or `returns setof`) PostgreSQL will do a good job.

```
drop table foo cascade;
NOTICE:  drop cascades to 2 other objects
DETAIL:  drop cascades to function getfoo(integer)
drop cascades to function getfoo2(integer)
```

Answer (score 3):

The different modes are interchangeable in some circumstances, but are different. What `RETURNS TABLE` is good for is described in the sentence you removed from your quote above:

> This is equivalent to using one or more OUT parameters plus marking the function as returning SETOF record (or SETOF a single output parameter's type, as appropriate).

This means that `CREATE FUNCTION ... RETURNS TABLE` is intended to specify a custom return type, i.e. it is equivalent to `CREATE TYPE xxx_t AS ([fields...,]); CREATE FUNCTION xxx ... RETURNS SETOF xxx_t`, and also `CREATE FUNCTION xxx ([in params...,] out [fields...,]) RETURNS SETOF RECORD`.

I.e., a function cannot return a table of some other table's type: use `RETURNS SETOF` directly for that (as you did in the snippet in your question).

Comment: Hi.  We are in 2020!  No news? It **is impossible** to reuse the table as a TYPE? like we do with columns (`table_name.column_name%TYPE`)... No way to express `RETURN table_name%TYPE`??

Comment: Note: the `RETURNS SETOF RECORD` [remembered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46721603/287948) is not the same thing.

Comment: @PeterKrauss `RETURNS SETOF <table_name>` or `RETURNS TABLE (LIKE <table_name>)`

Comment: When using a custom type and `RETURNS TABLE (LIKE my_type)` I got error "RETURN NEXT cannot have a parameter in function with OUT parameters". (the result set rows were all null without the NEXT parameter). When I switched to `RETURNS SETOF my_type` and was able to give NEXT a parameter, it worked great.